# Adobe Analytics API v 2

Tags: api, oauth, adobe, adobe-analytics

A little baffled by the Adobe Analytics Oauth integration.  I have done many OAuth implementations with other providers in the past, and used the older versions of the Adobe Analytics API.

My company provides services to clients who use Adobe Analytics, we do not have an account of our own.  In the past we just needed to be provided the user and shared secret and we were good to go.  Now it seems that we need to have an integration created by an admin in the client company, and have them send us the client_id and client_secret securely.  This does not grant us access instead it is the first step in requesting access.  Once we have this information we can do an OAuth request, using a valid adobe id with proper access and then we will receive the token we need to request data.

With other OAuth integrations I have seen, the client_id and client_secret are not tied specifically to a given account, but rather to the application.  In this case it seems we will need to have a new set of client_id and client_secret created for one application, for each account we need access to.

**To clarify the use case.**

> I work for Define Media Group an Audience Development Consulting Firm
>   specializing in SEO.
>
> Many of our clients are news organizations, for our purposes here,
>   lets say our client is the fictitious Newscor.  Newscor uses Adobe
>   Analytics and has come to us to provide insight into how they can
>   improve their SEO performance.
>
> As part of our analysis of Newscor we will need to look at the
>   Analytics data for all of the requests to their site from Googlebot. 
>   We will use the Adobe Analytics Reporting API to retrieve this data
>   and perform our analysis.
>
> In the case of a second fictitious company, Newscom, who instead used
>   Google Analytics, I built an application, I logged in with a Define
>   Media Group account to the Google API Console and generated a service
>   account for my application.  This provided the client id and secret
>   needed for completing the OAuth process.  Now I just need to have our
>   SEO contact at Newscom, access our page and complete the OAuth process
>   with his credentials and I will be able to complete the analysis on
>   his behalf.  Very straight forward.
>
> In the case of Newscor, I am stuck.  I have asked my SEO contact at
>   Newscor to have a service account created and provide the client id
>   and secret.  Instead he provided me his username and password.  I told
>   him that was not what I needed and would not work, confused he has a
>   user account created for me, and again I have to inform him that this
>   will be useful, but is not what I need.  I send over a link to the
>   Adobe documentation on how to create an integration account, before
>   following those directions I am sent a few other random strings of
>   characters in hopes that one of them will give me the data I need. 
>   Finally, the integration account is created and the client id and
>   secret are pasted into an email and sent to me over SMTP, plain text
>   you know.  Because users understand security and the complex side of
>   OAuth, so it is totally reasonable to have them sending client
>   secrets.

Yes the old credentials were also broken, I thought perhaps, a new API
based on a community standard would resolve that, instead it seems to
have made it worse.  Instead of sending me one set of credentials he
has to send me two sets, the client id and secret and a username and
password for an adobeid.  The idea behind OAuth as I understand it was
to entirely eliminate this and require that they send me no secrets,
but rather visit a secure page and grant me authorization through the
OAuth process, a familiar login and a few clicks, with secure exchange
of information.  The OAuth client_id were between me and Adobe where I
was able to download that information through Adobe's secure website. 
That same client_id and secret will be used when Newscom converts to
Adobe Analytics, or another client comes to us with an Adobe Analytics
account.

Avoiding third parties needing to exchange secrets is a primary reason that Oauth exists.  Requiring exactly that exchange makes this less secure than a username and password alone.

Posting here, because that is where Adobe directs people to ask questions.

Is this really the way that the new Adobe API works for OAuth or is there something I am missing?

Does it seem reasonable to expect each client to generate a new application integration?

Answer (score 0):

> Does it seem reasonable to expect each client to generate a new
>   application integration?

Well this is just opinion, but yes, I do think it is reasonable to expect each client (Company) to generate their own application Integration.

FYI, the previous user/shared secret you are used to *is* also tied to an individual adobe analytics account, and *is* also something the client would have had to setup and provide.

> In this case it seems we will need to have a new set of client_id and
>   client_secret created for one application, for each account we need
>   access to.

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by this. What exactly are you looking to do with your app? For example, if you are using the Adobe Analytics Reports API, you have the Integration credentials + Your own credentials and you can make Report requests with just that. You do not need credentials for any other user account.

Or, if you have a web interface, you have the option to have the users authenticate with their own credentials.

Overall, the Integration is the middle-man between the Adobe APIs and the user(s) requesting them.  The users use their own credentials that they should already have.

Here is an example of it in action (press the login button at the top of the page): https://adobedocs.github.io/analytics-2.0-apis/

Under the hood, there is only one Integration setup, and any individual authenticates with their own Adobe ID login credentials, and what they can actually do within the app depends on what kind of permissions their Adobe ID has for that company.

Perhaps it would be easier to explain the flow if you provide example of what your app actually does?

Comment: So something exactly like adobedocs.github.io, where all I had to provide was my user account to access my data.  But where did it get the client_id and client_secret to generate an oauth token using my login data?

Comment: I thought I was clear about the use case but perhaps not.  We work with many companies each company has their own Omniture account that they want to give us access to, so that we can perform analysis of the data on their behalf.  Based on what I saw at adobedocs.github.io, I did not need to provide a service/integration account only my user id and password, which did not have administrative access.  That is what we want to achieve.  How can we do that when the client id and secret are tied to the account and a new integration is needed for each account.

Comment: Whoever set it up created an Oauth Integration https://github.com/AdobeDocs/analytics-2.0-apis/blob/master/create-oauth-client.md each client will have to do this.

Comment: Except this is not the case.  I was able to use that integration with my clients data without setting up an Oauth integration.  Further I did successfully get one of my clients to setup an OAuth integration so that I can build my own tool, and those Oauth integration credentials work to complete the OAuth process for different totally unrelated clients data.  Just as one would expect the OAuth integration credentials are not limited to the account on which they were created.  As these credentials grant no access to data, there is no reason to require an analytics account to create them.

Comment: Okay well IMO that sounds like a bug on Adobe's end that should be reported.  Even if it is working as intended (though not really clearly conveyed in the docs), I would still be weary of this, and do it on a per-client basis.  What if you have ClientA set this up for you, and you use it for ClientB, and then one day ClientA decides to turn it off?

Comment: Exactly.  Except that I will never be able to get a client to deliver credentials securely, They don't understand even what that means.  I thought maybe, I would just have them do a screen share, and grab the credentials that way but before I was done, they were copied and pasted into a chat.  Actually relayed, because they didnt have my chat info directly.  If it were tied to the client you would never be able to create a tool like the one above.

Comment: @AaronM Did you ever get this sorted? I'm at a bit of a loss where to start. I've done planty of Google, FB, Twitter etc. implementaitons and even AA implementations using JWT, but I'm in the same boat now, needing to authenticate on behalf of a user. Do you have a reference implementation you can share or can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @DaveDavis I did not.   At the time I found that it just wasnt ready yet, it wasnt possible and they were not offering accounts to third parties.  Since then I have moved on and it is no longer a priority for me.

Comment: @AaronM Thanks for getting back to me. Unfortunately, it's still the same. Was looking up the Fivetran BigQuery connector setup and even they have to jump through the same hoops so I guess if my users want to use AA, they'll have to send secrets. Bit shocking to be honest. I'm glad you had the opportunity to move on! Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah it is pretty ridiculous.  But par for the course with Omniture, I had hoped Adobe ownership would put that on the right track but hasnt.   Omniture is a local company and I actually spoke to one of the project managers about this.   They dont get it, I guess they dont want to actually build an app ekosystem.